# cocos2d:Drawing CCSprite from one layer to another

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

**cocos2d:In** general , this situation : There are two layers :
1) HelloWorldLayer (main ) and Hudlayer :

```
@ implementation HelloWorldLayer.
+ (CCScene *) scene
{
/ / 'Scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene * scene = [CCScene node];
    
/ / 'Layer' is an autorelease object.
HelloWorldLayer * layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];
    
/ / Add layer as a child to scene
[scene addChild: layer];
    
    HudLayer * hud = [HudLayer node];
    [scene addChild: hud];
    layer.hud = hud;
/ / Return the scene
return scene;
}

- (id) init
{
if ((self = [super init])) {
...}
```

In HelloWorldLayer have a method that should be added to the layer CCSprite HelloWorldLayer

```
- (void) CreateSprite {
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector]. WinSize;
        CCSprite * sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @ "bird.png"];
                    sprite.position = ccp (winSize.width / 2 , winSize.height / 2);
        [self addChild: sprite];
}
```

In Hudlayer a button and a method that works when you press the

```
@ implementation HudLayer

- (Id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
                CGSize size = [CCDirector sharedDirector]. WinSize;
       CCMenuItem * Button = [CCMenuItemImage
                    itemFromNormalImage: @ "1.png" selectedImage: @ "1.png" target: self selector: @ selector (Build :)];
        CCMenu * menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: Button, nil];
        [menu alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding: 20] ;
        [menu setPosition: ccp (-Button.contentSize.width / 2 + size.width, size.height- 100 ) ] ;
        [self addChild: menu];

    }
    return self;
    
}
- (void) create: (id) sender
{
    HelloWorldLayer * create = [[HelloWorldLayer alloc] init];
    [create CreateSprite];
}
```

Appears on the screen button , when clicked, the method should work HelloWorldLayer CreateSprite and the screen should be added Tstssprite . Method that works , but why is not the sprite is added , no error is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you are doing is you are making all new object of HellowroldLayer and then you are calling create function from that object. So your sprite will add to that object. but as your new object is completely different from the old one so you're not getting sprite added to old object.

So in this case what you can do is give tag to your object,like,

```
self.tag = 777;
```

then in your create method,you can take that object from tag and then you can create method.

```
CCScene* scene1 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
if (scene1) {
   id layer1 = [scene1 getChildByTag:777];
   [layer1 CreateSprite];
}
```

No, need to make new object.

Comment: Does not work and it is not entirely clear)) Could you write like me to put in and tried? Very bad speak English, sorry))

Comment: I HudLayer there are methods by which displayed Hud, over the main HelloWorldLayer. And since you did, I do not quite understand, but I think it's not.